# Trying to build artifact with TeamCity and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity, maven-3, java-10

I have a maven3 project using Java10 with JavaFX and I´m trying to create an artifact with TeamCity through Windows. In Intellij I have no problem creating the artifact. The artifact is an exe file with several dependencies.

In TeamCity, I used the auto detected build-steps.

This is my first build step; this one was auto generated by Team City:

[image]

I was with the idea that maven was not being reimported so I created the second build-step:

[image]

The third build-step, also generated by TeamCity give me a problem.

[image]

This one can´t find my dependencies and returns an error for each one, something like:

> C:\BuildAgent\work\233ce8c2d06945e1\src\main\java\api\APIInterface.java:5: error: package retrofit2 does not exist

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. create the maven build step.
2. setup path to pom,
3. add goals `clean install`.

```
steps {
        maven {
            name = "test"
            goals = "clean install -U test"
            runnerArgs = """
                -T 1C
                -DskipTests=false 
            """.trimIndent()
            localRepoScope = MavenBuildStep.RepositoryScope.MAVEN_DEFAULT
            jvmArgs = "-Xmx2048m"
        }
    }
```

Don't use IDEA project